# Tiempo de espera agotado cuando ejecuto aplicacion

Tags: c#, visual-studio, configuración, webservice

Cuando ejecuto mi applicacion que llama varios servicios web, esta me lanza un error mencionando al tiempo de espera agotado.

He tratado de adaptar de varias formas mi archivo app.config pero me sigue dando el mismo error.

Alguna idea de como puedo arreglar esto?

Aqui esta el codigo de mi archivo de configuracion:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b012542c561934e089" >
            <section name="ExportDetails.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b012542c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <applicationSettings>
        <ExportDetails.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="ExportDetails_WebServices_list"
                serializeAs="String">
                <value>https://localhost/webservicetest/list.asmx</value>
            </setting>          
        </ExportDetails.Properties.Settings>      
    </applicationSettings>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="20480" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependiendo de si se trata código de cliente o de servidor (o para ir sobre seguro -- ambos):

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <netTcpBinding>
      <binding name="longTimeoutBinding"
        receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
        <security mode="None"/>
      </binding>
    </netTcpBinding>
  </bindings>

  <services>
    <service name="longTimeoutService"
      behaviorConfiguration="longTimeoutBehavior">
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost/longtimeout/"
        binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="longTimeoutBinding" />
    </service>
....
```

Sustituye el nombre del WebService por el que toque (y los bindings tienen que tener sentido con el WCF)

Comment: muchas gracias si me funciono!